# Import tab delimited data into MySQL using R

Tags: mysql, r

Is there anyways we could import a tab delimited text file to a MySQL database using R?

Thanks

Comment: What have you attempted thus far? For instance, have you even investigated ways of connected R to a MySQL db?

Comment: I used RODBC package to connect R with MySQL. I can read a table or send queries to MySQL. For this, I dumped the text file to the database using MySQL "load data" query. My question is, can I load data(text file) into a MySQL database and index it using R?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. If you've read the documentation for RODBC then you already know that you can create and populate tables from R (and you'd know how to do it, too). And if you can send SQL to the db from R, then you can create an index.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
mydata <- read.table("c:/mydata.file", header=TRUE, 
     sep="\t", row.names="id")
```

Sourced from [here](http://www.statmethods.net/input/importingdata.html)

And `read.delim` might also be worth looking at if `read.table` does not work.

Comment: I'm not talking about reading a file into R. It's about dumping a text file into a MySQL database using R

Comment: Okay... that would load the file up and then you could populate the table using the data read from the file.

Answer (score 0):

I would transform the `tsv` file into a `csv` file using `sed`, then I would import the file into `MySQL`.

Using `SED`, search for the tab, then replace that with a comma, then output to a new file.

Here is the example I tested with:
tab.tsv file:

```
Name    Age Address
Paul    23  1115 W Franklin
Bessy the Cow   5   Big Farm Way
Zeke    45  W Main St
```

`sed` command

```
sed s/'     '/,/g tab.tsv > tab.csv
```

tab.csv looks like this now:

```
Name,Age,Address
Paul,23,1115 W Franklin
Bessy the Cow,5,Big Farm Way
Zeke,45,W Main St
```

Note: `sed` does NOT like `\t`, so you need to actually enter a `tab`.  Use `command` `v`, then hit `tab`.  Make sure your wrap an apostrophe around the `tab`.

Now that the data is in a `CSV`, choose your preferred way to import the file into `MySQL`.